# Spark job fails with org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Glue job that process about 500MB of data. There are a bunch of outer join operations in my code, and there are 2 dataframes with size is 1 million rows. The outer join operations do not blow up, and the maximum size of all resultant dataframes post transformations is always <= 1M rows. I observed that my job fails with the `org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle` error, and after a lot of googling, it seems like this is an OOM error. I have benchmarked the job and see that the input data/shuffle data size for each executor is in a matter of MBs (< 100MB). I am confused as to how this can be an OOM error when the data size is significantly smaller than the memory size of the G2.X machine in Glue.

I am able to get rid of the failure in the following 2 ways:

1. By removing a repartition step in my code
2. When the failure happens, I have set the Number of workers to 10, but when I reduce the number of workers to 3, I notice that the job succeeds.

How could removing a repartition (which even though generates a lot of shuffle data and is expensive, but the size of data is still small), or reducing the number of workers solve an OOM issue.